# Discord bot using python not being able to read messages

Tags: python, discord.py

The discord bot is able to run and goes on the server, it is also able to detect when a message is sent but it cannot read the message. the code is: (the MY_TOKEN will be the actual bot token)

```
import discord
import os

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  print('Received message:', message.content)
  if message.author == client.user:
    print('cancelled message')
    return
  
  if message.content.startswith('hello'):
    print('sent message')
    await message.channel.send('pls work')

client.run(MY_TOKEN)
```

I tried giving it administration abilities and kicked and readded the bot but the resault was still the same, the logs look like:

Logged in as GD Transfer Bot#6486
Received message:
Received message:

Answer (score 1):

Because reading message requires the bot to have `message_content` intent specifically. Just add it like the way you added members and presences intent.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for a bot to read messages, they need to have the [message_content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#message-content) explicitly set as `True`, this is the same with all intents. Add the intent like so:

```py
intents.message_content = True
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try it without explicitly setting up the intents? I'm looking at my bot and everything I do is pretty much the same, except the `client = discord.Client()` part.

Comment: when i remove the intent stuff i get this error:        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    client = discord.Client()
TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Comment: I ought to update my code then.

Comment: Have you enabled the intents in the bot's dashboard?

Comment: simply enable message_content intent.